# Outlook Add-In tutorial?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

Does anyone know of a good example for getting started with Outlook add-ins using C#?

Comment: If you are interested please commit for this : stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two ways to create such an add-in in VS 2008:

1. Managed Add-in (File > New Project > Office > Outlook 2007 Add-in)
2. Shared Add-in (File > New Project > Other Project Types > EXtensibility > Shared Add-in)

For Managed Add-in:

- [Getting Started (Office Development in Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/library/23cw517s%28en-us%29.aspx)

An example of a Shared Add-in:

- [Creating Custom Task Panes as COM Add-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338197.aspx#office2007createcustomtaskpanes_creatingcustomtaskpanesascomaddins)

For comparison:

- [Visual Studio Add-ins Versus Shared Add-ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165620(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [Shared Add-in vs. VSTO Add-in: What's the difference between/how can I tell if I'm developing?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3f97705a-6052-4296-a10a-bfa3a39ab4e7)

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN blog article here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx)

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the "How Do I" videos on MSDN:

[How do I... (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863719.aspx)

[Forms (Outlook How Do I)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866705.aspx)

Also - get to know the [Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866465.aspx)

And the difference between [Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860356.aspx) and [Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869356.aspx) windows.

Along with the other articles, posted, you'll be up and running in no time at all.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend taking a look at Addin Express.

They have a toolset that

1. offers more features than out-of-the-box Visual Studio, and
2. reduces the amount of required code (i.e. makes it easier).

Here is an [overview of the Add-in Express features for Outlook](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/programming-outlook.php).