# Outlook 2010 add-in first time

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I need to create an add-in to my outlook 2010. 
I have started a new project with office outlook 2010 template, and didn't add any code.

When I click the F5(run) the outlook 2010 application starts to load but gets stuck on "in process".

I'm using VS 2010 C# with outlook 2010.

As I didn't add any code to the add-in (I just ran the default template code), why is it stuck?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can suggest is to maybe add some code in the `ThisAddIn_Startup()` method, for example:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup()
{
  MessageBox.Show("It did something!");
}
```

and see if you see a message on the screen. If it doesn't, put a breakpoint on the line (or even the add-in entry point) and see if it hits it.

The next thing I could suggest is to have a read on SO, namely under the `outlook-addin` tag, and possibly search the web on some starting points:

Heres one to get you going:

[Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755001/outlook-add-in-tutorial)